# Drag & Drop a photo file to QGraphicsView

Tags: c++, qgraphicsview

How to let QGraphicsView handle drag and drop? Say, drag an image file from some folder and then drop to QGraphicsView? Windows, QT5.2, C++.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to make a subclass of QGraphicsScene (if you haven't done so already) and override its dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *) method to call acceptProposedAction() on its argument if the argument represents an image file you would be able to handle -- i.e. if dragDropEvent->mimeData()->hasUrls() returns true, and at least one of the QUrls returned by dragDropEvent->mimeData()->urls() can be used to construct a valid QPixmap (via QPixmap(url[i]->toLocalFile)).

Then you'll need to override the dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *) method to create a new QGraphicsPixmapItem object (with a QPixmap created with the filename specified in the QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent object's mimeData object) and add the QGraphicsPixmapItem to the QGraphicsScene.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to add a `QGraphicsItem` to the scene, and `setAcceptDrops(true)` on the item. The `background` item does this work in the following code.

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDragEnterEvent>
#include <QGraphicsRectItem>
#include <QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QUrl>

class MyGraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT

  protected:
    QGraphicsRectItem* background = nullptr;

  public:
    MyGraphicsScene()
    {
        this->addItem( this->background = new QGraphicsRectItem(0, 0, 1, 1) );
        background->setAcceptDrops(true);
    }

    virtual void resize(int width, int height)
    {
        this->background->setRect(0, 0, width - 1, height - 1);
    }

  protected:
    virtual void dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent* event) override
    {
        if ( event->mimeData()->hasUrls() )
            event->acceptProposedAction();
    }

    virtual void dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent* event) override
    {
        if ( event->mimeData()->hasUrls() )
            foreach ( const QUrl& url, event->mimeData()->urls() )
                qDebug("GraphicsScene: dropped %s", qPrintable(url.toLocalFile()) );
    }
};

class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT

  protected:
    MyGraphicsScene myGraphicsScene;

  public:
    MyGraphicsView()
    {
        this->setScene( &this->myGraphicsScene );
    }

  protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event) override
    {
        this->myGraphicsScene.resize( event->size().width(), event->size().height() );
    }
};

class MyMainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

  protected:
    MyGraphicsView* myGraphicsView = nullptr;

  public:
    MyMainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        this->setAcceptDrops(true);
        this->setCentralWidget(this->myGraphicsView = new MyGraphicsView());
    }

  protected:
    virtual void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent* event) override
    {
        if ( event->mimeData()->hasUrls() )
            event->acceptProposedAction();
    }

    virtual void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event) override
    {
        if ( event->mimeData()->hasUrls() )
            foreach ( const QUrl& url, event->mimeData()->urls() )
                qDebug("MainWindow: dropped %s", qPrintable(url.toLocalFile()) );
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow myMainWindow;
    myMainWindow.show();
    return application.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```